# How to use the deltaMethod function in R to compare coefficients from two different glms?

Tags: r, regression, approximation, coefficients

I am trying to check if the difference between two coefficients extracted from two equation is greater than zero using the [`deltaMethod` in R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/msm/versions/1.6.9/topics/deltamethod)

```
set.seed(111)
y1.predict <- rnorm(12,3,1)
y1.n1 <- c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000,0,0,0,0,1000,4000,3000,3000)
y1.n2 <- c(0,0,0,0,1000, 2000, 3000, 4000,4000,1000,2000,2000)


y2.predict <- rnorm(16,5,1)
y2.n1 <- c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000,0,0,0,0,1000,4000,3000,3000,1000,0,2500,4000)
y2.n2 <- c(0,0,0,0,1000, 2000, 3000, 4000,4000,1000,2000,2000,0,4000,2500,0)


df1 <- data.frame(y1.predict, y1.n1,y1.n2)
df2 <- data.frame(y2.predict, y2.n1,y2.n2)


y1 <- lm(y1.predict ~ n1 + n2)
y2 <- lm(y2.predict ~ n1 + n2)


#Typical use of delta method when comparing coefficients from same regression. Here I am trying to see if n1 - n2 > 0
g1.delta <- deltaMethod(y1,"(-n1) - (-n2)")
```

What I need is to compare the coefficient of `n1` of `y1` and `n2` of `y2` using the delta method. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deltaMethod(...)` extracts the variance covariance matrix from the fitted model object (the `lm` object in your example). If you are comparing two regressions, based on different data, you don't know the vcov.

If you assume `n1` (from `fit.1`) and `n2` (from `fit.2`) are independent, then you could use `deltaMethod(...)` this way:

```
df1   <- data.frame(y1.predict, n1=y1.n1, n2=y1.n2)
df2   <- data.frame(y2.predict, n1=y2.n1, n2=y2.n2)
fit.1 <- lm(y1.predict ~ n1 + n2, df1)
fit.2 <- lm(y2.predict ~ n1 + n2, df2)
#
means <- c(coef(fit.1)['n1'], coef(fit.2)['n2'])
##
# assumes independence (covariance = 0)
#
vcov  <- diag(c(summary(fit.1)$coefficients['n1', 2],
                summary(fit.2)$coefficients['n2', 2])^2)
deltaMethod(means, 'n1-n2', vcov)
##            Estimate          SE       2.5 % 97.5 %
## n1 - n2  6.3295e-05  2.7686e-04 -4.7934e-04  6e-04
```

Since the 95%CL includes 0 you cannot conclude the n`s are different.

BTW your code does not run as presented. This will likely discourage ppl from responding to your questions.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answer. I am curious, is there another method to test if the coefficients are significantly different from zero then the delta method that assumes independence (cov = 0)?

Comment: `deltaMethod` isn't assuming cov = 0, I am. AFAICT you are comparing the result of 2 models using different data sets. If cov(n1, n2) within each model is similar, you could use that. You'd need much more information about the problem to do more.